# Data to be send back to Machine in ASTM PROTOCOL

Tags: lis

I'm designing an LIS application that will communicate to Lab Machines.I had successfully implemented unidirectional flow of Machine but now I am trying to implement Bidirectional flow for the machine.Whenever I'm sending data to  machine it is returning me Nak and I'm unable to know the issue for the same.The machine is COBASC311 which is working on ASTM Protocol.Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A Laboratory Machine replies you with NAK either if it is busy or if it doesn’t accept the message you send. In your case probably something goes wrong with the message.

I have faced plenty of times such kind of problems. I would recommend you :

1. Make sure that you construct the record message as the documentation of Cobas C311 (Generally Roche delivers reliable documentation). Watch out if you omitted an essential field and generally if you “put” the necessary data to the related fields.
2. Check the alerts at the GUI of the analyzer. Roche has a very friendly user interface. At the alerts you can see ALL the warnings/errors of the Cobas C311 (e.x. reagents warnings, barcode errors etc.). So, if you try to send the specific message , you will observe that an alert will be raised regarding LIS communication and if you open this alert you can see more details. In most cases the message was descriptive and I could solve the problem.

Hope this was helpful, if you cannot understand what exactly the problem is you can upload the related alert message here to help you.